# How do I make featureLayer inactive in Mapbox layer toggle?

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I have a simple layer toggle of featureLayers and tileLayers. The toggle buttons remain active when turned off only for the featureLayers. I've looked at the reference documentation, but can not see why only the featureLayer is not working correctly:

[Map demo](http://erichsen-group.com/demoland/Rene/)

```
 var baseLayer = new L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapster.l4b4kjoi');
 this.className == 'active';
var ui = document.getElementById('map-ui');

var future = L.mapbox.featureLayer('mapster.l4pda0e3');
var demand = L.mapbox.featureLayer('seamap.l50l5ecd');
var historic = L.mapbox.featureLayer('mapster.l4pda0e3');
var navwater = L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapster.ydvyqcpm');
var coasturban = L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapster.znl98dfb');



addLayer(future, L.mapbox.gridLayer('mapster.l4pda0e3'),'Future Projects', 4);
addLayer(demand, L.mapbox.gridLayer('seamap.l50l5ecd'),'Current Read-Mix Demand', 4); 
addLayer(historic, L.mapbox.gridLayer('mapster.l4pda0e3'),'Historic Read-Mix Use', 4);
addLayer(navwater, L.mapbox.gridLayer('mapster.ydvyqcpm'),'Navigable Waterways', 3);
addLayer(coasturban, L.mapbox.gridLayer('mapster.znl98dfb'),'Coastal Urban', 4);


function addLayer(layer, gridlayer, name, zIndex) {
    layer
        .setZIndex(zIndex)

    gridlayer
    // add the gridControl to the active gridlayer
    var gridControl = L.mapbox.gridControl(gridlayer, {follow: true}).addTo(map);

    // Create a simple layer switcher that toggles layers on and off.
    var item = document.createElement('li');
    var link = document.createElement('a');

    link.href = '#';

     link.innerHTML = name;

link.onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

   if ($(this).text() == 'Toggle All Off') {
        map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
         map.removeLayer(layer);
         map.legendControl.removeLegend(layer.getTileJSON().legend);
        });
        this.className = '';
        map.addLayer(baseLayer);
    } else
    if (map.hasLayer(layer)) {
        map.removeLayer(layer);
        map.removeLayer(gridlayer);
        // you had "thelayer", but it should be "layer":
        map.legendControl.removeLegend(layer.getTileJSON().legend);
        // change two lines that were here to the following:
        this.className = '';
    } else {
        map.addLayer(layer);
        map.addLayer(gridlayer);
        this.className = 'active';
        map.legendControl.addLegend(layer.getTileJSON().legend);

    }


};
    item.appendChild(link);
    ui.appendChild(item);
}
```

Comment: You've forgot to include your own Mapbox accessToken: `L.mapbox.accessToken = '<your access token>';` and again your question is very very thin. What did your research turn up? What did you try? Why didn't it work? What errors are you getting? I'de suggest you read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask thoroughly and learn to form better questions because we're not magicians.

Comment: @iH8 is right : you have a bunch of "401 Unauthorized" exceptions. Some objects are not loaded, hence the errors. Please consider installing something like [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to debug your javascript and examine the errors